# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline tests fails to connect to MongoDB Atlas even though my local machine testing does

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gitlab, nestjs, pipeline

When running NestJS tests in my local machine all tests runs smoothly and no error arises. However, when my pipeline runs tests on Gitlab, it fails to connect to the MongoDB Atlas giving the following error.
**ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database.**

From doing my own tests on the pipeline I have noticed that environment variables are indeed recognized by the pipeline environment and that my MongoDB atlas is allowing all IP addresses to access it, so I have no idea what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gitlab yml file (take note for node image I have also tried **latest**):

```
stages:
  - backend

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .npm/

backend:
  image: node:14.17.0
  stage: backend

variables:
  ABASSES_PASSWORD: $ABASSES_PASSWORD
  ABASSES_USERNAME: $ABASSES_USERNAME
  ADMIN_PASSWORD: $ADMIN_PASSWORD
  ADMIN_USERNAME: $ADMIN_USERNAME
  ERICS_PASSWORD: $ERICS_PASSWORD
  ERICS_USERNAME: $ERICS_USERNAME
  JWT_SECRET: $JWT_SECRET

script:
  - cd ./src/nestjs-backend
  - npm ci
  - npm run lint
  - npm run build
  - npm run test

artifacts:
  paths:
    - .env

only:
  - backend
```

Pactum test file for NestJS server:

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as pactum from 'pactum';
import { INestApplication, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module';
import { UserDto } from 'src/users/dto/user.dto';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  describe('App e2e', function () {
    let app: INestApplication;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      jest.setTimeout(24000)
      const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [AppModule],
      }).compile();
      app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
      app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
      await app.init();
      await app.listen(5000);
      pactum.request.setBaseUrl('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
    });
    afterAll(() => {
      app.close();
    });

    describe('User authorization', function () {
      let randomString = '';
      const possibleCharacter =
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYMJUIKOLP';

      for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        randomString += possibleCharacter.charAt(
          Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleCharacter.length),
        );

      const dto: UserDto = {
        username: `${randomString}@gmail.com`,
        firstName: 'Eric',
        lastName: 'Test',
        password: 'r43rfe$£fed!',
      };

      describe('Participant signup', () => {
        it('Should throw error if first and last names are empty', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/signup')
            .withBody({ username: dto.username, password: dto.password })
            .expectStatus(400);
        });

        it('Should throw error if username is empty', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/signup')
            .withBody({
              firstName: dto.firstName,
              lastName: dto.lastName,
              password: dto.password,
            })
            .expectStatus(400);
        });

        it('Should throw error if password is empty', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/signup')
            .withBody({
              username: dto.username,
              firstName: dto.firstName,
              lastName: dto.lastName,
            })
            .expectStatus(400);
        });

        it('Should signup if all parameters are correctly provided', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/signup')
            .withBody(dto)
            .expectStatus(201)
            .stores('participantId', '_id');
        });
      });

      describe('User login and deletion', () => {
        it('Should throw error if username empty', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/login')
            .withBody({ password: 'cdscds' })
            .expectStatus(401);
        });

        it('Should throw error if password empty', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/participant/login')
            .withBody({ username: 'dswdesw' })
            .expectStatus(401);
        });

        it('Should throw error if body is empty', () => {
          return pactum.spec().post('/auth/login').expectStatus(404);
        });

        it('Should login with admin account', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .post('/researcher/login')
            .withBody({
              username: process.env.ADMIN_USERNAME,
              password: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
            })
            .expectStatus(201)
            .stores('jwt', 'jwt');
        });

        it('Should delete previously created account', () => {
          return pactum
            .spec()
            .delete('/admin/participant/delete/$S{participantId}')
            .withHeaders({ Authorization: 'Bearer $S{jwt}' })
            .expectStatus(200);
        });
      });
    });

  });
});
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated I've spent countless hours trying to resolve this issue.